# Removing item out of nested document array and while also accounting for null/empty document array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongodb and I've been working on this query for quite sometime. I've found solutions using "$project" and "$group" and "$match". Overall goal is if document within nested array "internal" attribute is false, remove it from the array.

**$project** and **$group** DO work BUT they then throw of the projection, I don't even see a current projection in this query but once I add in **$project**  or **$group** it ONLY returns the specific nested document array I'm messing with.

**$match** won't work because I have cases where the parameter in question that I'm using to remove items from the nested document array is true or false or the array is empty, and **$match** in different use cases just doesn't return the main document.

Here's an example **$group**

```
{ '$unwind': '$notes' },
  {
$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  notes: {
    $push: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $eq: [ "$notes.internal", false ] },
        then: "$$REMOVE",
        else: "$notes.internal"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use $addFields with $filter:

```
{$addFields: {
    notes: {$filter: {
       input: "$notes",
       as: "item",
       cond: {$ne: [ "$$item.internal", false ]}
    }}
}}
```

Comment: thanks man! I didn't know about addFields, it worked.